# Visible lag while scrolling two way scrolling UICollectionView with large number of cells (250,000 or more)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in order to get two way scrolling in a `UICollectionView`. The scrolling works fine for smaller number of row and section count (100-200 rows and sections) but there is visible lag while scrolling when I increase row and section count over 500 i.e 250,000 or more cells in the `UICollectionView`. I have traced the source of the lag to be for in loop in the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`. I am using a `Dictionary` to hold `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` of each cell to avoid recalculating it and looping through it to return attributes of cells from `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`

```
import UIKit

class LuckGameCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    // Used for calculating each cells CGRect on screen.
    // CGRect will define the Origin and Size of the cell.
    let CELL_HEIGHT = 70.0
    let CELL_WIDTH = 70.0

    // Dictionary to hold the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for
    // each cell. The layout attribtues will define the cell's size
    // and position (x, y, and z index). I have found this process
    // to be one of the heavier parts of the layout. I recommend
    // holding onto this data after it has been calculated in either
    // a dictionary or data store of some kind for a smooth performance.
    var cellAttrsDictionary = Dictionary<NSIndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()
    // Defines the size of the area the user can move around in
    // within the collection view.
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return self.contentSize
    }

    override func prepareLayout() {

        // Cycle through each section of the data source.
        if collectionView?.numberOfSections() > 0 {
            for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections()-1 {

                // Cycle through each item in the section.
                if collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0 {
                    for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)-1 {

                        // Build the UICollectionVieLayoutAttributes for the cell.
                        let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)
                        let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                        let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                        let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: cellIndex)
                        cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                        // Save the attributes.
                        cellAttrsDictionary[cellIndex] = cellAttributes
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // Update content size.
        let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections()) * CELL_HEIGHT
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)

    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        // Create an array to hold all elements found in our current view.
        var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Check each element to see if it should be returned.
        for (_,cellAttributes) in cellAttrsDictionary {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellAttributes.frame) {
                attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
            }
        }

        // Return list of elements.
        return attributesInRect
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath]!
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
Following are the changes that I have come up with in the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {        
    // Create an array to hold all elements found in our current view.
    var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    let xOffSet = self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x
    let yOffSet = self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y
    let totalColumnCount = self.collectionView?.numberOfSections()
    let totalRowCount = self.collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0)

    let startRow = Int(Double(xOffSet!)/CELL_WIDTH) - 10    //include 10 rows towards left
    let endRow = Int(Double(xOffSet!)/CELL_WIDTH + Double(Utils.getScreenWidth())/CELL_WIDTH) + 10 //include 10 rows towards right
    let startCol = Int(Double(yOffSet!)/CELL_HEIGHT) - 10 //include 10 rows towards top
    let endCol = Int(Double(yOffSet!)/CELL_HEIGHT + Double(Utils.getScreenHeight())/CELL_HEIGHT) + 10 //include 10 rows towards bottom

    for(var i = startRow ; i <= endRow; i = i + 1){
        for (var j = startCol ; j <= endCol; j = j + 1){
            if (i < 0 || i > (totalRowCount! - 1) || j < 0 || j > (totalColumnCount! - 1)){
                continue
            }

            let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: j)
            attributesInRect.append(cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath]!)
        }
    }

    // Return list of elements.
    return attributesInRect
}
```

I have calculated the offset of the collectionView and used it to calculate the cells that will be visible on screen(using height/width of each cell). I had to add extra cells on each side so that when user scrolls there are no missing cells. I have tested this and the performance is fine.

Comment: Obviously the looping through the dictionary is the expensive part.  I wonder if there's someway to key your dictionary so you could get everything that intersects with a rect without needing to loop through 250k values.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I thought about that as well but the problem is that `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect ` doesn't necessarily return only the visible elements. 
From the  doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)
`Based on the current scroll position, the collection view then calls your layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: method to ask for the attributes of the cells and views in a specific rectangle, which may or may not be the same as the visible rectangle.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By taking advantage of the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect)` with your known cell size you don't need to cache your attributes and could just calculate them for a given `rect` as the collectionView requests them. You would still need to check for the boundary cases of 0 and the maximum section/row counts to avoid calculating unneeded or invalid attributes but that can be easily done in `where` clauses around the loops. Here's a working example that I've tested with 1000 sections x 1000 rows and it works just fine without lagging on the device:

Edit: I've added the biggerRect so that attributes can be pre-calculated for before the scrolling gets there. From your edit it looks like you're still caching the attributes which I don't think is needed for performance. Also it's going to lead to a much larger memory footprint with the more scrolling you do. Also is there a reason your don't want to use the supplied `CGRect` from the callback rather than manually calculate one from the contentOffset?

```
class LuckGameCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

let CELL_HEIGHT = 50.0
let CELL_WIDTH = 50.0

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)) * CELL_WIDTH
    let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections()) * CELL_HEIGHT
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let biggerRect = rect.insetBy(dx: -2048, dy: -2048)
    let startIndexY = Int(Double(biggerRect.origin.y) / CELL_HEIGHT)
    let startIndexX = Int(Double(biggerRect.origin.x) / CELL_WIDTH)
    let numberOfVisibleCellsInRectY = Int(Double(biggerRect.height) / CELL_HEIGHT) + startIndexY
    let numberOfVisibleCellsInRectX = Int(Double(biggerRect.width) / CELL_WIDTH) + startIndexX
    var attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    for section in startIndexY..<numberOfVisibleCellsInRectY
        where section >= 0 && section < self.collectionView!.numberOfSections() {
            for item in startIndexX..<numberOfVisibleCellsInRectX
                where item >= 0 && item < self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) {
                    let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)
                    if let attrs = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(cellIndex) {
                        attributes.append(attrs)
                    }
            }
    }
    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let xPos = Double(indexPath.row) * CELL_WIDTH
    let yPos = Double(indexPath.section) * CELL_HEIGHT
    let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)
    return cellAttributes
}
}
```

Comment: Can you check my update with the solution that I came up with and any feedback on that.

Comment: Any suggestion on getting this to work for different cell width?  Thanks!

Comment: @Unikorn If you mean to have different cell widths for each cell it is certainly harder. You could possibly save the attributes in Dictionary as in the original example from the question above, but that would increase the memory footprint, or store the x offset for each section (row in this case) that would increment as the user drags toward the right or decrements when dragging to the left and is calculated based on the total width of visible cells plus the cell spacing. I'm sure there would be problems with this that would need further exploring but that could be a start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with a data structure for your cells which is ordered by dimension(s), in order to come up with some algorithm using those dimension(s) to narrow down the search range.

Let's take the case of a table with cells 100 pixels tall by the full width of the view, and 250_000 elements, asked for the cells intersecting { 0, top, 320, bottom }. Then your data structure would be an array ordered by top coordinate, and the accompanying algorithm would be like

```
let start: Int = top / 100
let end: Int = bottom / 100 + 1
return (start...end).map { cellAttributes[$0] }
```

Add as much complexity as your actual layout requires.

Answer (score 1):

`cellAttrsDictionary` is inappropriate to store the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. It's indexed by `NSIndexPath` but in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` you are searching for an area. If you need `cellAttrsDictionary` for something else then you could leave it but store each cellAttribute **additionally** in another data structure which is faster to search.

For example a nested array:

```
var allCellAttributes = [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()
```

The first level array describes an area, let's say it's in chunks of 1000 pixel high and full screen width. So all cellAttributes which intersect with the rectangle { 0, 0, screenwidth, 1000 } go into:

```
allCellAttributes[0].append(cellAttributes)
```

All cellAttributes which intersect with the rectangle { 0, 1000, screenwidth, 2000 } go into:

```
allCellAttributes[1].append(cellAttributes)
```

And so on...

Then, in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` you can search in this data-structure by jumping directly into the array depending on the given CGRect. If the rect is e.g. {0, 5500, 100, 6700} then you just need to search in this range:

```
allCellAttributes[5]
allCellAttributes[6]
```

This should give you the basic idea, I hope you understand what I mean.